# Convert unix time to UTC date/time in PHP

Tags: php, timezone, unix-timestamp

The UTC day 2022-12-11 starts at unix time 1670716800 (which is obviously divisible by 24*3600).

In PHP, I can convert it from left to right this way:

```
$Date = "2022-12-11";
echo strtotime ($Date." 00:00 UTC");
```

As expected, the output is 1670716800.

But how to convert it back? If I do `getdate(1670716800)`, I get a date with a time, but in my local time zone, whereas I want UTC.

I do not want to use object oriented PHP if this can be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1670716800)` returns `"2022-12-11 00:00:00"`.

`gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s")` returns the current GMT/UTC time in that format (since the GMT time is defined to be equal to the UTC time).

Answer (score 0):

My timezone is UTC so you will get different results, but use the  `date_default_timezone_set()` function to dafine what the `date()` function will do with the timestamp

```
$Date = "2022-12-11";
$tstamp = strtotime ($Date." 00:00:00 UTC");

echo date_default_timezone_get() . '-';
echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s', $tstamp) . PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL;


date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo date_default_timezone_get() . '-';
echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s', $tstamp) . PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL;

date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane');
echo date_default_timezone_get()  . '-';
echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s', $tstamp) . PHP_EOL;
```

RESULTs

```
UTC-2022/12/11 00:00:00

America/Los_Angeles-2022/12/10 16:00:00

Australia/Brisbane-2022/12/11 10:00:00
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$timestamp = 1607980736;
$utc_date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
echo $utc_date_time;
```

Output:
2021-12-11 16:45:36

Comment: No, this result is also in my local time zone instead of UTC.